# FormulaArray keeps changing to relative references

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to enter a formula in a sheet using VBA (for later use in Excel Solver). It worked fine until this morning.

```
For u = 1 To Row2
            Sheets("Testa").Cells(u + 1, 14).FormulaArray = "=SUM(IF(B2:B2000=" & CStr(u) & ",F2:H2000,0))"
        Next
For v = 1 To Row
            Sheets("Testa").Cells(v + 1, 18).FormulaArray = "=SUM(IF(A2:A2000=" & CStr(v) & ",F2:H2000,0))"
        Next
```

The first loop gives this as a result in the cell: "=SUM(IF(RC[-12]:R[1998]C[-12]=1,RC[-8]:R[1998]C[-6],0))", changing the absolute references to relative references and not translating the functions to the french equivalent. The second loop works just fine. Column A and B contain a list of numbers (from 1 to Row or Row2) that look like this :

```
1 1
1 2
1 3
2 1
2 2
2 3
3 1
3 2
3 3
```

I don't know what I'm missing. Any help is welcome !

Comment: You need to appropriately use $ in yoru ranges, such that if you want strictly row 2 col 2 looked at, you use $B$2, and if you want a dynamic column, but always row 2, you use B$2.

Comment: I tried changing that but it doesn't make a difference. I'll add that to the first message but my Excel is in french. The second loop that gives a correct results translates the formula into frnech, the first loop doesn't. This might be the problem rather than the references in hindsight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The range where I was writing the formula was set up as a text range, explaining why it didn't compute the formula. Changing it manually to a standard range solved the problem.